# Vuetify3 data-table responsive

Tags: datatable, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, vuetify-datatable

I upgraded from Vuetify2 to Vuetify3 and noticed that the `v-data-table` component isn't responsive anymore
How can I restore its responsiveness in Vuetify3?
Any suggestions or code examples would be very helpful

picture of docs vuetify2 , `data-tabel`

[image: picture of docs vuetify2]

picture of docs vuetify3 , `data-table` not responsive

[image]

Comment: It's not a problem for SO.  It's an issue with the library and should be discussed on [their github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/16784).